# How to use the same random seed between Windows Devices?

Tags: c#, windows, random, synchronization, hololens-emulator

I am trying to shuffle cards in a deck using the same random seed so the decks will be random, but synced on both clients. I am using the following shuffle algorithm:

```
    internal void ShuffleDeck(int randomSeed)
    {
        _random = new Random(randomSeed);
        Cards.Card[] toShuffle = CardsInDeck.ToArray();
        Shuffle<Cards.Card>(toShuffle);
        CardsInDeck = toShuffle.ToList<Cards.Card>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shuffle the array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Array element type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">Array to shuffle.</param>
    private static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // NextDouble returns a random number between 0 and 1.
            // ... It is equivalent to Math.random() in Java.
            int r = i + (int)(_random.NextDouble() * (n - i));
            T t = array[r];
            array[r] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
    }
```

When I run two instances of my card game on the same machine, the cards are shuffled and synced on both clients as expected, but when I run one instance on my computer and another in a HoloLens emulator, the cards use the same seed, but cards are not synced. Is there anyway to shuffle the cards and have them synced across multiple clients?

By Synced, I mean they are shuffled in the exact same way. IE when I run both clients the first time with four cards (a,b,c,d) the deck order is (b,c,a,d) on both clients. When I run the clients the second time the deck order is (c,d,a,b) on both clients.

Comment: If you used a Mersenne Twister, you could simply share the current seed and both would generate the same sequence of values.  BTW, that is an imperfect shuffler.

Comment: @Plutonix what is an imperfect shuffler? Is there a Mersenne Twister built in to c#?

Comment: It is flawed - it should move each item once and only once by not considering it when subsequent items are moved.

Comment: See https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/ for the reason why your shuffle is not correct. And for a correctly implemented shuffle.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for that article. I "naively" just googled shuffle algorithm c# and got http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle and copied it. It seemed like it worked, but your article explains why it is not. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to make sure that both machines are using the exact same seed *and* the same random number generator. There's no guarantee that different versions of the `Random` class will use the same algorithm.

So you need to develop your own random number generator class and use it instead of `System.Random`.

Comment: That stinks. Why would System.Random be different? Thanks that pretty much answers my question, but I have no idea how to make a random class...

Comment: @SethKitchen: Why it would change might be that they found a bug, or that they came up with a faster algorithm. As for making your own, one thing you *could* do is get the source for the existing `System.Random` from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca, copy the code to your project, change the name to `MyRandom`, and then wherever you use `System.Random` in your code, reference `MyRandom`. Or, you could do some research and develop your own pseudo random number generator. It's not that difficult.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: About your comment's second sentence: Take a look at the license agreement for the reference source found in referencesource.microsoft.com.

Comment: @PeterO. Noted.

Comment: Just to add to my comment. I meant to add "I am not a lawyer", but I couldn't edit that comment to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my own answer here.

A simple 52 card shuffle can take as few as 29 bytes or (more practically) 52 bytes, which most applications may consider as "not much".  It would be a better idea, in my opinion, to [store the shuffled deck, in this case, rather than the seed](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#When_to_Use_a_Seeded_PRNG), unless your application shows your users a code for your players to regenerate the shuffled deck.  This way, you won't have to tie your application to a particular RNG (such as `System.Random`).